# I have multiple employees shipping orders. Is there any way to track which user shipped which order?

Tags: admin, orders, shipping

I have multiple employees shipping and invoicing orders, they each have their own log in. I need a way to figure out what employee shipped what order. Some type of logging extension that I can type in a order number and see who shipped the order and who invoiced it.

Comment: Everything is done in the order? If so, you'll need an extension that hooks onto the event dispatched after a shipment is created and log the user somewhere in the DB with your observer. Does this help?

Comment: Do you have a recommendation on an extensions that will do this for me?

Comment: Meant to ask "everything is done in the admin?" And I don't know of any extension that does what you need. Try search on Google.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [FireGento admin monitoring](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-adminmonitoring) extension before. This extension builds an admin grid that allows you to easily see what users have done what in the admin section.